# Avoid duplication of event in queue?

Tags: events, caching, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm using `Windows Azure` for development,

In my application `data` is taken from `cache` if data is not present in `cache` then it will generate a event and insert that into `queue` then `Webjob` will fetch data from `database` put it inside `cache`.

Is there any other good approach for this ?

second here if other call comes that also check data into `cache` and tries to put event into `queue` which eventually called by `Webjob` and data inserted from `database` to `cache`

> 1.May I know any good approach for event based opeartion?
>
> 2.If i took this approach which is the best way to avoid duplicate

Comment: Why are you using queues/WebJob to populate the data in cache? There would be some delay in populating the cache as WebJob will poll the queue to get the message. Why not follow this approach: `Check Cache --> Cache is Empty --> Put data in cache`?

Comment: Web project hits cache to check data if data not there event will be created to get data from database insert into cache ? what you think about this? as you said How we can identify cache is empty ? using Webjob or Event ?

Comment: That's my question exactly. Why not populate the cache in the web project itself? You can check if the cache is empty by reading the item from cache ... you know something like .... `var obj = ReadFromCache(key)`. if `obj` is null that would mean it is not there in the cache. If it is null, then just do `WriteToCache(key, ReadFromDB())` to write an item into cache.

Comment: in your case what if data gets modified in database ? we will get old data in cache ?

Comment: actually i'm working on platform + framework project - so by using our framework other developers will use these feature , dats why I can not load cache in web project

Comment: Regarding `what if data gets modified in database` ... as part of your database writes, you will have to ensure that cache is also updated at that time so that cache always holds the most current data. Regarding `i'm working on platform + framework project` ... without understanding the project in full details, it would be hard to comment. But I am assuming your framework is a class library project that gets included in all of your projects (including web) so your cache management mechanism would be consistent. HTH.

Comment: Perfect great help :) thanks a lot will keep in touch , great stuffs on your blogs too :)